# Why flexbox truncate / slip under outer element?

Tags: flexbox

[image]

This should be here an `ON` button, but sometimes Safari renders it badly, in Chrome it is always works. Normally it looks like this:

[image]

Here `enableSaleBlock` is the flex parent.

[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

.enableSaleBlock { width:90%;}